# what are all the files that I need to install glade gtkbuilder and gtk - x

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade, gtkbuilder

I am having a hard time searching for gtkbulider as it does not show up in my Debian repos, is that Glade by another name?

Gtk comes in 3 different versions, 1, 2, 3. what is the best version to install to go along with what version Glade and lets not forget about this GtkBuilder I cannot find by name to install.

I have just installed Glade 3.12.1 and it says it is missing

```
GladeUI-Message: 2 missing displayable value for GtkWidget::events
GladeUI-Message: No displayable values for property GtkTreeSelection::mode
GladeUI-Message: 14 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererAccel::accel-mods
```

What are all the packages that I need to install to get all three of them to happily work together? As I am planing on trying to learn how to use it using C as my Programming Language.

What are some good sources with examples and understandable documentation to read the how to's and what for's to help me get a good basic understanding of how to put all three of these together so that they all wokr together to make one happy program that hopefully runs with little to no errors?

And, does this GTK and Glade GtkBuilder only work Linux running Gnome or can these apps that are build by these programs  be ran on Debian openbox,and all the other Linux flavors what do not use Gnome, like KDE for instance, or is it just Gnome specific only?

Answer (score 2):

You can create gtkbuilder files with the glade interface designer (at least with newer versions, round about 2 years). In your application (the one you write/compile) use the `GtkBuilder` object to load the widget-tree from the file. `.glade` is just a different (afaik) format to store the widget-tree.

As of now I'd recommend Gtk+ 3.x - from my personal experience things are a lot more thought out and less evolutionary (read: backwards compat) cruft is kept.

As long as the target has a somewhat recent (which has GtkBuilder support) glib/gtk+ library you should be fine. gtk+ is multiplatform, and GtkBuilder is part of it - nothing gnome specific.

Use the [devhelp](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Devhelp) application for quick and easy doc access (install the doc packages, coming from a fedora background)

Comment: thank you I'll install and experiment -- thanks again.